# How to force download of file from Google Team Drive using Google Drive API libraries in Java

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api

In my application, I am trying to force a download of a file from a Google Team Drive when the user clicks on a link on a form in my application.

A few updates:

1. I have code that can upload to the Team Drive as well as create    folders on the Team Drive.
2. The "Team Drives support - This application works properly with files    in Team Drives." on the Google Drive API settings CANNOT be enabled -    I can check this box, but I cannot click the Save Changes button,    since the button is always disabled.  However, I don't think that is    the issue, since I can interact with the Team Drive in my code.

I have read the Google documentation, which is very limited:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get

I have also read through a few posts:

[Download files from google drive using java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45182550/download-files-from-google-drive-using-java-api)

But, I can't find an answer that works.  I have built some code which uses a Service Account.  The code sets the drive service and uses the Service Account as the credentials.  I based the download part of my code from this Google documentation example:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#examples

Here is the code I am using:

```
public static void downloadFile(String fileID) {
    // Set the drive service...
    Drive service = null;
    try {
        service = getDriveService();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        service.files().get(fileID).executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
        // NEED CODE HERE???????


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Build and return an authorized Drive client service.
 * 
 * @return an authorized Drive client service
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static Drive getDriveService() throws IOException {
    Logger.info("GoogleDrive: getDriveService: Starting...");
    GoogleCredential credential = null;
    Drive googleDrive = null;
    try {
        credential = authorize();
        Logger.info("GoogleDrive: getDriveService: Credentials set...");
        googleDrive = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return googleDrive;
}

/**
 * Creates an authorized Credential object.
 * 
 * @return an authorized Credential object.
 * @throws IOException
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static GoogleCredential authorize() throws IOException {
    GoogleCredential credential = null;
    String credentialsFileName = "";
    try {
        Logger.info("GoogleDrive: authorize: Starting...");

        Logger.info("GoogleDrive: authorize: Getting credentialsFileName path...");
        credentialsFileName = Configuration.root().getString("google.drive.credentials.file");
        Logger.info("GoogleDrive: authorize: credentialsFileName = " + credentialsFileName);

        Logger.info("GoogleDrive: authorize: Setting InputStream...");
        InputStream in = GoogleDrive.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(credentialsFileName);
        if (in == null) {
            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: authorize: InputStream is null");
        }
        Logger.info("GoogleDrive: authorize: InputStream set...");

        Logger.info("GoogleDrive: authorize: Setting credential...");
        credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(in, HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY)
                .createScoped(Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
        System.out.println("Could not find file " + credentialsFileName);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    Logger.info("GoogleDrive: authorize: Ending...");
    return credential;
}
```

When my code runs, there are no errors and nothing happens.  I am guessing I am missing some code in the downloadFile function.  If I am missing something or incorrect in my coding, please feel free to provide examples or the correct code I should be using.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This demo does not use service accounts.*

I'm just going to demonstrate how I downloaded a Team drive file and hopefully it gives you insight on your project.

The foundation of the code was taken from [Drive API Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java):

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();

       //this is what you're looking for - a way to download a file using 'webContentLink'
        try {        
              Desktop desktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
              //place your webContentLink in the oURL variable
              URI oURL = new URI("https://drive.google.com/a/google.com/uc?id=YOUR_FILE_ID&export=download");
              desktop.browse(oURL);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Upon execution, this program opens a blank browser window and downloads the file to your computer.

The way I generated the `webContentLink` was just use the [Files.get Try-it](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) and made sure I set `supportsTeamDrives` to `true` and also setting `fields` parameter to `webContentLink` so it returns just that.

Of course you can always use the Java `files.get` programmatically to fetch `webContentLink` but fetching the `webContentLink` using the Try-it was easier for testing purposes.