# try this API , what parameter need to be passed in these fields

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get#try-it

```
Request parameters
fileId
acknowledgeAbuse
supportsTeamDrives
```

First of all, I am new to this Google API 
I have no idea what values to pass in these boxes and what they are used for.
I passed `fileId` with a file name in Google Drive, I don't see any `id` in property of file too. Also `acknowledgeAbuse` will be `True`.

Comment: Maybe try getting the list of available files first?
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list

Comment: without teamDriveId getting 400 error what value to specify

Comment: id = yOuRId  , and other option as true still got 403

Comment: Setting `acknowledgeAbuse` to true is only applicable to download request as stated in the 403 error message. I've also tested it in files that is not in the Team Drive and received the same error message. Once the `acknowledgeAbuse` is set to `false`, I've successfully get 200 message and file details. If you still need to download the file, try this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51168565/5995040).